# Backward Compatibility of Pacts

Tags: versioning, pact, pact-broker

How can I verify the pacts against all the different consumer versions. Whenever I try to test the pact , it only verifies the latest one. Is there a way to also verify the older consumer versions.

[image: Table view]

I also tried with the ConsumerVersionSelector option . However the production version don't seem to verified

```js
consumerVersionTags: ['master','production'],
      consumerVersionSelectors: [
        {tag: 'master', latest: true },
        {tag:'production'},
]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "all of the consumer versions". In the image shown, do you have both versions `1.0.0` and `2.0.0` in production? This is usually not the case, but can be common in cases like mobile where there are indeed multiple versions deployed at once.

Assuming it *is* what you need...

You need to set `latest: false` - from the [docs](https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/advanced_topics/consumer_version_selectors/):

> `latest`: Whether or not to verify only the pact that belongs to the latest application version. The most common use case is to set this to true. When false, null or omitted, the pacts that belong to all application versions with the specified tag will be verified. This is to support the scenario when an API has many production versions, and hence pacts (eg. a mobile consumer).

You should also probably not use `consumerVersionTags` in conjunction with `consumerVersionSelectors`, especially if the tags overlap, as it may override the selectors (i.e. setting `latest: true`).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out. However one more question.  Imagine there is a consumer version 1.0.0 in the broker , and lets say a new consumer comes in and lets say in the api spec , he/she doesn't  have an email-ID property. For this, I create a new version 1.0.1 and publish to broker. When I try to run the provider only the newer version (i.e 1.0.1) i.e without the email-ID property is verified successfully and the old one(1.0.0) with the email-ID fails. How do I make sure that the old consumer version (1.0.0) is also verified successfully,orwouldthatscenario neve happenin realife?

Comment: That's a legitimate, and normal thing. TL;DR - you would use tags for that. The new feature would would first have a tag like "development" and would only be merged and deployed once the pact passes. The provider would verify both "development" and "production". See https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/workshops/ci-cd and https://docs.pact.io/pact_nirvana for guidance on this workflow.